# Is there any other way to hide dropdown menu when clicked outside?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So, I am creating a dropdown menu in React and if I click outside the dropdown menu, it should close. For that, I am currently using click eventListeners. Is there any other way that can be used instead of using eventListeners? I tried with onFocus and onBlur, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code snippet:

```
const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
const dropdownRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    //hiding the dropdown if clicked outside
    const pageClickEvent = (e: { target: unknown }) => {
      if (dropdownRef.current !== null && !dropdownRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setShowMenu(!showMenu);
      }
    };

    //if the dropdown is active then listens for click
    if (showMenu) {
      document.addEventListener("click", pageClickEvent);
    }

    //unsetting the listener
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", pageClickEvent);
    };
}, [showMenu]);

<Button onClick = {() => setShowMenu(!showMenu)} />
{showMenu ? (
     <div className="dropdown-content" ref={dropdownRef} >
        <a>
        ...
        <a>
      </div>
    ) : null}
```

Comment: The code you have is a common and established pattern. Are you facing *some* issue?

Comment: Nope. This works fine. But writing unit tests for this seems a bit complicated. So, wanted to know if there are any other alternate approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Use an overlay under the menu.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [menuVisible, setMenuVisible] = useState(false);
  
  
  return (
    <div>
    
      <button className='dropdown-button' onClick={() => setMenuVisible(true)}>Click me</button>
      
      {menuVisible ? (
        <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
          {/* items go here */ }
        </ul>
      ) : null}
      
      {/* now the important part */}
      
      {menuVisible ? (<div className='overlay' onClick={() => setMenuVisible(false)} />) : null}
    
    </div>
  
  )
}
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks!

Note: You need to add z-index for the dropdown inorder to make it click-able.

Comment: @SaravananManoharan that's correct, or render it before the menu.